# complex multidimentional associative array process with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I've had to ask this one again, sorry, but I'm having a problem trying to process this array. I have tried several different ways but none where right, here's the array:

```
Array ( 
  [search] => Array ( 
    [response] => Array ( 
      [errors] => 
      [number_of_hotels] => 1 of 1 
    ) 
    [lr_rates] => Array ( 
      [hotel] => Array  ( 
        [hotel_ref] => 3116 
        [hotel_currency] => [U] => USD 
        [hotel_rooms] => Array ( 
          [room] => Array ( 
            [ref] => 6382 
            [type] => 1 
            [type_description] => Standard 
            [sleeps] => 8 
            [rooms_available] => 
            [adults] => 8 
            [children] => 
            [breakfast] => false 
            [dinner] => false 
            [description] => 
            [alternate_description] => 
            [rack_rate] => 82.01 
            [date] => 19/08/201220/08/201221/08/2012
            [numeric_hotelcurrencyprice] => FullFullFull
            [formatted_date] => 19 August 201220 August 201221 August 2012 
            [price] => FullFullFull
            [hotelcurrencyprice] => FullFullFull 
            [numeric_price] => FullFullFull
            [requested_currency] => GBPGBPGBP 
            [numeric_hotelcurrencyprice] => FullFullFull
            [available_online] => false 
            [minimum_nights] => 1 
            [bed_type] => 
            [cancellation_policy] => 
            [cancellation_days] => 
            [cancellation_hours] => 
            [room_terms] => 
          )
          [room] => Array ( 
            [ref] => 6382 
            [type] => 1 
            [type_description] => Standard 
            [sleeps] => 8 
            [rooms_available] => 
            [adults] => 8 
            [children] => 
            [breakfast] => false 
            [dinner] => false 
            [description] => 
            [alternate_description] => 
            [rack_rate] => 82.01 
            [date] => 19/08/201220/08/201221/08/2012
            [numeric_hotelcurrencyprice] => FullFullFull
            [formatted_date] => 19 August 201220 August 201221 August 2012 
            [price] => FullFullFull
            [hotelcurrencyprice] => FullFullFull 
            [numeric_price] => FullFullFull
            [requested_currency] => GBPGBPGBP 
            [numeric_hotelcurrencyprice] => FullFullFull
            [available_online] => false 
            [minimum_nights] => 1 
            [bed_type] => 
            [cancellation_policy] => 
            [cancellation_days] => 
            [cancellation_hours] => 
            [room_terms] => 
          )
        ) 
        [cancellation_type] => First Night Stay Chargeable 
        [cancellation_policy] => 2 Days Prior to Arrival 

        [CityTax] => Array ( 
          [TypeName] => 
          [Value] => 
          [OptedIn] => 
          [IsCityTaxArea] => 
        )
      )
    )
  ) 
)
```

Ok, I need to traverse the array and create a loop, so for every instance of ROOM it will repeat the process. Then i need to extract the data from room array and use it to populate rows in MySQL for each instance of room.

This is the code I have so far which prints the names and values in the room array. However, it only gets one of the room arrays. **What can I do to read all of the rooms?** I am also thinking this is too many for-each but don't seem to be able to traverse down ['']['']['']... 
or by just using the associative name.

```
foreach($arr['search'] as $lr_rates) {
        foreach($lr_rates['hotel'] as $hotel) {
                   foreach($hotel['room'] as  $field => $value){
                     print $field;print $value;
                          }

             }
      }
```

It might also be worth mentioning the values in these arrays are always fluctuating.

Comment: What is the question? Please use punctuation, your post is unreadable.

Comment: good then when you have a question let us know

Comment: I edited the post to improve readability and bolded the question. I just need someone to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can really simplify this quote a bit.  If you know that this will always be the structure then you can jump right down into the hotels and then into the rooms.

```
foreach($arr['search']['lr_rates']['hotel'] as $hotel) {
      // You can access all of the keys in the hotel array here

      foreach($hotel['hotel_rooms'] as $room) {
          // Do stuff with the room array
      }  
}
```

I would recommend either building your insert script on the fly and calling the database just once for the write, or if you are updating then using a transaction.  As the number of rooms gets larger you will slow your script down with a bunch of writes to disk.

Answer (score 2):

the formatting of your data's output is very bad and unreadable. I cannot really identify what you are trying to do.

1. possibility: the inner array `[hotel_rooms] => Array ()` uses the key `room` multiple times. as array keys are unique, you overwrite the data at the index `room`. this is why you only get one room.
2. possibility: there are `rooms` inside a `room` -> use a recursive function to iterate over all rooms like this:

   ```
   function handleRoom(array $room) {

       // do something with $room

       if (array_key_exists('room', $room)) {

           handleRoom($room['room']);
       }
   }

   $room = array(
       'some' => 'room',
       'data' => 'and another',
       'room' => array(
           'is' => 'inside',
           'of the' => 'main room',
       ),
   );

   handleRoom($room);
   ```