# whats the best way to process an xml to MySql in php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

hi guys been struggling with this for a while, i can do xsl transformation on the data and that works to output the data, but i want to save the data i have tried automatically generating an array like shown here [complex multidimentional associative array process with foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042496/complex-multidimentional-associative-array-process-with-foreach) but this didn't work as there are multiple accounts of room and i can only have the name ['room'] once in an array

so i need to know the best way to get xml to MySql using php

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)? It seems to me that all you need is to save it as a large string (varchar or text).

Comment: haha, Matt :D you post it so often :D

Comment: @AndreasLinden it's a great blog article!

Comment: i believe Ive tried almost everything thinking simple xml and xpath is about the only thing in php i havent tried

Comment: acctualy i have tried it but its the only thing i have tried but not got as far as outputting anything xslt does the job but as its not a complete application just a single xsl i dont know how to set it up to go into sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easy way is to use PHP's integrated SimpleXML